# Online Marketing company want me to share my Google Account login details? Is this normal practice?

Tags: security, marketing, google-plus, google-local-search, accounts

We are a small business and use "[Google Apps for Work](https://www.google.com/intx/en_uk/work/apps/business/)" and my google apps account was used to set up the business's "[Google My Business](https://www.google.ie/business/)" and related Google+ pages

We have now engaged an online marketing company to manage the business's online local marketing. But they are asking us to share our Google Account login details so they can manage the business's "Google My Business" and related Google+ pages.

I have no issue letting them into any online marketing related tools such as the Google My Business account and related Google+ pages (and I presume they may also want access to our Google Analytics), but the same Google account login details would also give them access to my other Google business apps such as my gmail and google drive which I am very uncomfortable with.

How can I give them access to the google marketing tools, which were set up under my name, but not the more sensitive apps? What is the proper security practice to allow third parties to access the marketing tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't give your Google passwords to anyone. Pretty much every Google business tool should allow you to delegate access to additional Google accounts.

Here are support pages for adding users to several Google services.

- [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702)
- [Google My Business/Google+ pages](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3403100)
- [Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2453966)

Answer (score 0):

You can share the Gmail Login Credentials to them if you trust them.
The other method is you can provide them permission access to your Analytics account by https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en this procedure.

It is always recommended to follow the second method in which your personal Gmail & Google Drive information is not accessible to them.

Comment: No. Someone should never be asked to share their login details and you shouldn't recommend it. Not to mention that Google will probably flag it as an suspicious login and require secondary verification specifically because it's a terrible thing to do.